# Does CoreML work with the swift package manager?

Tags: swift, coreml, swift-package-manager

Can I use the CoreML framework in a Swift package manager executable?
Or is it limited to iOS and OSX apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Core ML currently only runs on iOS or macOS. Apple isn't in the habit of making their frameworks available for other platforms. ;-)