# How to use CoreML Model in a Swift Package Manager macOS Command Line App?

Tags: swift, coreml, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to create a command line app ***that runs on macOS*** and uses CoreML. I am using Swift Package Manager. Here are some steps to reproduce the problem:

- Run

  ```
  swift package init --type executable
  ```
- Move a CoreML model into the `Sources` folder, for example, CNNEmotions.mlmodel
- In `main.swift`, write

  ```
  print(CNNEmotions()) // CNNEmotions is the name of the generated model type
  ```
- [I know that CoreML only runs on macOS and iOS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055956/does-coreml-work-with-the-swift-package-manager), so in `Package.swift`, I added a platform parameter:

  ```
   let package = Package.init(
       name: "MyProject",
       platforms: [
         .macOS(.v10_13), // this is the minimum macOS version that supports CoreML
      ],
  ...
  ```
- Run

  ```
  swift build
  ```

And there will be an error saying that `CNNEmotions` is an unresolved identifier.

If I do `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and open up the project in Xcode, I can see that the `.mlmodel` file is not added to the project at all!

[This person on Apple Forums seems to also be in the same situation as me, but there are no answers to their question...](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81415)

How can I make SPM work with mlmodels?

---

Just when I thought it's the end of the world, I found that *if I add the .mlmodel file into the project in Xcode, the program can compile and run successfully*. But the problem with building it in Xcode is that it's quite inconvenient. It doesn't produce an executable in a convenient location (I have to go all the way to the DerivedData folder to find it). To be honest, I would just like a convenient command to build & run it, like `swift build`. This is my ultimate goal.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I've just found out that you could generate the model manually using `xcrun coremlcompiler generate /path/to/model.mlmodel --language Swift /path/to/output/model.swift`